# just one div scrollable on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need nothing on page to be scrollable except one div (`divleft`), and it should be scrollable by mouse, not by scrollbar. All scrollbars should be hidden.

I treid a solution with narrower parent div (`divleftwrap`), but id doesnt work.

```
<div id="slidetop">
323<br>
323<br>
323<br>
</div>
<div id="menutop"></div>
<div id="wrapt">
<div id="divleftwrap">
<div id="divleft">
...
</div>
</div>
<div id="divright">
...
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
#slidetop{
    display:none;
}
#menutop{
    height:25px;
    background:red;
}
#divleftwrap{
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    background:blue;
    height:100%;
}
#divleft{
    width:clac(100% + 17px);
    background:green;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#divright{
    width:25%;
  float:right;
    background:lightblue;
}
```

js - this should stay to work

```
$("#menutop").click(function(){
    $("#slidetop").slideToggle();
});
```

HERE IS [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bonaca/18agqyvy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a bit your style sheet due a little error. In order to verify the scroll I reduced the height.

In the following the snippet:

```js
$("#menutop").click(function(){
  $("#slidetop").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
html, body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
#slidetop{
  display:none;
}
#menutop{
  height:25px;
  background:red;
}
#divleftwrap{
  float:left;
  width:60%;
  background:blue;
  height:200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#divleft{
  width:calc(100% + 17px);
  height: 110%;
  background:green;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#divright{
  width:25%;
  float:right;
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div id="slidetop">
    323<br>
    323<br>
    323<br>
</div>
<p id="test"></p>

<div id="menutop"></div>
<div id="wrapt">
    <div id="divleftwrap">
        <div id="divleft">
            STARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTART
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            ENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDENDEND
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divright">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
        a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
        remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
        Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```